# Update only the time stamp in a MySql table

Tags: mysql

Given this table

```
mysql> describe last_user_activity;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| customer_id  | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| token        | text       | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_stamp   | timestamp  | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| is_logged_in | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to "touch" a row of the table, setting the `time_stamp` to its default, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I thought that I could try

```
UPDATE last_user_activity WHERE token="40aed4d9-c9ac-471e-8d53-b2baa0d72523";
```

(that is a valid token in the table), but that resulted in

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE
>   token="40aed4d9-c9ac-471e-8d53-b2baa0d72523"' at line 1

Oh, well, it seemed clever, but NVM. So, then I tried

```
UPDATE last_user_activity SET token="40aed4d9-c9ac-471e-8d53-b2baa0d72523" 
       WHERE token="40aed4d9-c9ac-471e-8d53-b2baa0d72523";
```

which said that it succeeded, ***BUT***, the timestamp field was not updated.

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Why not just `set time_stamp = current_timestamp` or `set time_stamp =  DEFAULT(time_stamp)`?

Comment: the default value is assigned  on creation  not after

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE last_user_activity 
SET time_stamp = NULL
WHERE token="40aed4d9-c9ac-471e-8d53-b2baa0d72523";
```

OR

```
UPDATE last_user_activity 
SET time_stamp = NOW()
WHERE token="40aed4d9-c9ac-471e-8d53-b2baa0d72523";
```

Comment: Setting to `NULL` did not work, setting it to `NOW()` did

Comment: Yes, because the default is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. `time_stamp` will be set only when you insert a new row. If you remove the default value (CURRENT_TIMESATMP), the value of `time_stamp` will be updated when you update the row. Read more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you have given default value of column time_stamp, but not on update.
You may considering this change :

ALTER TABLE last_user_activity
  MODIFY COLUMN time_stamp TIMESTAMP  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

I hope this works.After that you could try using your update commands.